# Ionic Infinite Scroll with ngrx-store

Tags: angular, ionic2, ngrx

I am trying to use [Ionic's Infinite Scroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/) with paginated data from an api that gets added to a ngrx store, but I'm not sure I fully understand how to make it work.

I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41822738/consuming-paginated-service-in-angular2-ionic2-using-observables#answer-41828845) for help with Observables, but getting data from the store is a little different. I can't subscribe to the response from the api since it is handled by an Effect.

Here's my simplified code:

Template

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of (items | async).results">
      <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="infiniteScrolling$.next($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Component

```js
export class InventoryPage {
  items: Observable<Items>;
  infiniteScrolling$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor(
    public store: Store<AppState>,
    public itemsActions: ItemsActions
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.store.select(appState => appState.items);
    this.store.dispatch(createAction('FETCH_ITEMS'));

    // What should this.infiniteScrolling$ do here since dispatching
    // actions does not return an observable?
  }
}
```

Store

```js
const initialState = { results: [] };

export function itemsReducer(items: Items = initialState, action: Action): Items {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_ITEMS_SUCCESS':
      return { results: [...items.results, ...action.payload.results] };
    default:
      return items;
  }
}
```

Am I on the right track and if yes, where should I call `infiniteScroll.complete()` once the data is returned from the api?

Comment: If you need an `Observable`, use `Observable.of` to create one. `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';`. You can also use  `Observable.from` to convert an array into an stream of its items. I do not think you need one though....

Comment: I see. What should I create an Observable from though?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using NgRx, the state of the loading spinner (whether it shows or is hidden) should be saved in your store. This is a bit tricky with Ionic's infinite scroll implementation, because the visibility of the spinner isn't tied to a variable than you can easily link to state. In their implementation, the spinner shows automatically when `ionInfinite` is emitted and you have to explicitly call `complete` on the event dispatched to hide it again.

It would be ideal if you could pass an input to the ion-infinite-scroll element to show or hide the loading spinner. Then you could save a `loading` variable in your store that captures the status of the request and pass this to the ion-infinite-scroll element. When ionInfinite is emitted, simply dispatch an action to fetch the next page of results. In your reducer, the request action should set `loading` to `true` (so the spinner shows) and the sucess action dispatched in your effects should set it back to `false` (so the spinner is hidden again).

Since Ionic doesn't do this out of the box, you could add a directive to achieve this behaviour:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInfiniteScroll]'
})
export class InfiniteScrollDirective implements OnChanges {

  @Input() loading: boolean;

  private event: CustomEvent;

  @HostListener('ionInfinite', ['$event'])
  public onIonInfinite(event: CustomEvent) {
    this.event = event;
  }

  public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.loading && !this.loading && this.event) {
      (this.event as any).complete();
      this.event = null;
    }

  }

}
```

Then add it to the ion-infinite-scroll element and pass your loading state variable to the `loading` input:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll 
  appInfiniteScroll
  [loading]="loading$ | async"
  (ionInfinite)="fetchNextPage()">
  <ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

I put together an example in a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-infinite-scroll) if it's helpful.

Comment: For Ionic 4, you must update it to (this.event as any).target.complete();

Answer (score 0):

I have this:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">

doInfinite(event) {
  this.store.dispatch({type: SET_FILTER, payload});
  event.target.complete();
}
```